# C# Fill combo box from SQL DataTable

Tags: c#, sql

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection _cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=COMNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASE; Integrated Security=True"))
{
    string _query = "SELECT * FROM Doctor";
    SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(_query, _cs);

    using (SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd))
    {
        _da.Fill(_dt);
    }
}
cbDoctor.DataSource = _dt;
foreach(DataRow _dr in _dt.Rows)
{
    cbDoctor.Items.Add(_dr["name"].ToString());
}
```

There was an Error...

The result is `System.Data.DataRowView` instead of data from database..

Comment: When you write `cbDoctor.DataSource = _dt;` is sets datasource to the `cbDoctor` control and should automatically add all the items from `dt` collection to it (you may also call `cbDoctor.DataBind()` to update the binding), so you don't have to manually add items. Please give more information i.e. is this a desktop app and what kind of control `cbDoctor` is.

Comment: desktop application, i just want to fill my combo box with data from datatable on form load..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not yet sure what is the exact error in your code, but if you're ok with not using `DataTable`, you can do it this way:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connstring"))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Doctor", sqlConnection);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        cbDoctor.Items.Add(sqlReader["name"].ToString());
    }

    sqlReader.Close();
}
```

For more information take a look at [SqlDataReader reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

In orer to find the issue in the original code you posted, please provide information in which line you get the exception (or is it an error that prevents application from compiling?) and what is its whole message.

Comment: how to do it with `SqlDataAdapter`

Answer (score 2):

You could also specify DisplayMember property of combobox to any of the column name.
For example if you want to display Name field, you could do

```
Combobox1.DisplayMember="Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to insert multiple columns into a comboBox (which can accept only one column). Adjust your SELECT statement so that it combines all of the data you need into one column:

Example:

```
SELECT Name + ' ' LastName + ' '+ ID AS 'DoctorData' FROM Doctor
```

By using the + operator you can combine multiple columns from the database, and represent it as a single piece of data. I think that your code should work after that (you can even comment the foreach loop, I think that adding data source  to your comboBox will be enough)

Comment: already done that, i just want to fill the combo box with names column  from data table

Comment: yeapp..

'System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView'

Comment: First, it's a little weird that you didn't open your connection - you should add this line `if(_cs.State == ConnectionState.Closed) _cs.Open();` before defining the SqlCommand.
Second, you should add that connection to the SqlComman with this line `_cmd.Connection = _cs`. I don't know why the compiler hasn't thrown that as an error, but try it.

Comment: @NDraskovic it's not weird that it's not opened, a dataadapter handles it automatically, it doesn't need to be explicitly opened.