# how i fill 2 comboboxs from 2 different tables?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I need to fill 2 comboboxs from 2 different tables. This way doesn't work.

```
private void client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SCP_DB;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();
    string query = "select  Operation_Type from Operations_Types";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Operations_Types");
    comboOpType.DisplayMember = "Operation_Type";
    comboOpType.ValueMember = "Operation_Type";
    comboOpType.DataSource = ds.Tables["Operations_Types"];

    da.Fill(ds, "Payment_Type");
    comboPayType.DisplayMember = "Payment_Types";
    comboPayType.ValueMember = "Payment_Types";
    comboPayType.DataSource = ds.Tables["Payment_Type"];
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can u show how ur tables look like ?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: there is now exception

Comment: the first como is working

Comment: @AlyRamadan I suggest you clarify in your question what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: This may help you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900062/c-sharp-fill-combo-box-from-sql-datatable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256832/c-sharp-fill-a-combo-box-with-a-datatable

Comment: Of course the second combo cannot be filled if you don't specify any query for the second table.

Comment: but the the other doesn't retrieve from database

Comment: You have _only_ **one** query and you try to fill your comboboxes with the _same_ data that comes from the _same_ table.

Comment: i edit it thank you very much it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call each table in your sql instance and also use the `TableMappings`

change your code like this.

```
private void client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SCP_DB;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();
    string query = "select  Operation_Type from Operations_Types; select ? from Payment_Type";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Operations_Types");
    da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Payment_Type");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Table");
    comboOpType.DisplayMember = "Operation_Type";
    comboOpType.ValueMember = "Operation_Type";
    comboOpType.DataSource = ds.Tables["Operations_Types"];

    da.Fill(ds, "Table1");
    comboPayType.DisplayMember = "Payment_Types";
    comboPayType.ValueMember = "Payment_Types";
    comboPayType.DataSource = ds.Tables["Payment_Type"];
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: glad to help you. Thanks.