# keeping rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

hy i want on a selected combo box value it move rows from database to datagridview

```
private void test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string    str = "select * from sale_tab";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["Item_name"].ToString());
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

it display rows but when i clicked next value in combo box it show new row but the first rows does not remain in gridview i want it hold all the row for example i click book from combo box it show display book detail and when i click computer it should add row under books detail

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

   str = "select * from sale_tab where item_name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
   cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
   sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   sda.Fill(ds, "sale_tab");
   dataGridView1.DataMember = "sale_tab";
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
   con.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your dataGrid swapping out all the options is because of these lines
  `DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
   sda.Fill(ds, "sale_tab");
   dataGridView1.DataMember = "sale_tab";
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;`
if you make a gobal datatable variable, then you can use a temp datatable in the method so you can combine the datatables together like this

```
Golbal variable:
datatable dtAll = new datatable();

//put this inside the method body
datatable _dt = new datatable(); 
  str = "select * from sale_tab where item_name='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
   cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
   using (SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd))
    {
        _da.Fill(_dt);
    }
   dtAll.Merge(_dt);

   dataGridView1.DataSource = dtAll;
   con.Close()
```

hope this helps

Comment: @pål-jørgenvaldersnesas I am new in .net will you please explain it further.

Comment: read this article and you should be able to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900062/c-sharp-fill-combo-box-from-sql-datatable 
the only difference is that you need to make local temp datatable so that you merge them with dtAll.Merge(dtTemp);

Comment: this article leads to how you add data in combo box but my problem is not adding data in combo box but on selecting combo box value it display data in grid view row wise like if i selected first item it show show all the detail and when i click second it should should all its detail ,thanks

Comment: Ive edited the answer to provide the exact stuff you need to fix, but the point of this site is mostly to guide you to find the answer you need, not nesecerily give you the code